# Sphinxsearch Aplhanumeric Query with No Results

Tags: php, search-engine, sphinx

I have a sphinx index which has about 5 million records.. Most of them are Aplhanumeric Number Plates like E2 LNK, B1 SOB, A1 CAS etc etc

When I search for keywords like "E2 LNK", the docs and hits for E2 are always zero, infact all the alphanumeric queries return zero result

Im using SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED mode

```
$this->sphinxclient->SetMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED);
$this->sphinxclient->SetSortMode(SPH_SORT_EXTENDED, "@relevance DESC");
$res = $this->sphinxclient->Query('E2 LNK', $index_sphinx);
```

Here is the index

```
source sphinx_index_numberplate
{

    type                                    = mysql
    sql_sock                                = /tmp/mysql.sock
    sql_host                                = localhost
    sql_user                                = user
    sql_pass                                = pass
    sql_db                                  = db
    sql_port                                = 3306

    sql_query_range                 = SELECT MIN(id),MAX(id) FROM plate
    sql_range_step                  = 1000

    sql_query                       =       SELECT id,id AS plate_id,number_first, number_second, number_third, plate_number, plate_number_full, LENGTH(plate_number) AS len, plate_type, is_available, price FROM plate \
                                           WHERE  id BETWEEN $start AND $end

            sql_attr_uint                                   =       plate_id
            sql_attr_uint                                   =       plate_type
            sql_attr_uint                                   =       price
            sql_attr_uint                                   =       len
            sql_attr_uint                                   =       is_available
}


index sphinx_index_numberplate
{
    source                  = sphinx_index_numberplate
    path                    = /usr/local/sphinx/data/sphinx_index_numberplate
    charset_type            = utf-8
    enable_star             = 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=7289

try adding min_word_len = 1,

also try exact matching by surrounding the query with quotes.

this might be a problem of sphinx take your input as 2 different words of 2 and 3 length each.

Have you tried command line search? it's results?